# tomcat jndi ldap userSearchAsUser not used

Tags: java, tomcat, ldap, tomcat7, jndi

When I configure this, it does not bind with the user (checked with wireshark on the ad server)
(only when I use userPattern, but I cannot seem to use that as it needs a single userformat user for both bind and search)
I don't want to have a username/password of a delegated user)

```
<Realm  className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm" 

        debug="99"

        connectionURL="ldap://x.1.1.22:389"

        userSearch="userPrincipalName={0}"

        userBase="cn=Users,dc=mydomain,dc=lab"

        userSubtree="true"

        userRoleName="memberOf"

        userSearchAsUser="true"

        />
```

tomcat 7.0.47

Answer (score 0):

There are some more parameters to add for search and bind. Use the connectionName and connectionPassword for the search.

An [example of use is shown here](http://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Tomcat%20And%20LDAP).

Comment: I have seen your example, but when I read the tomcat documentation, those 2 should not be required as I should be able to bind and search as the user

Answer (score 0):

The userSearchAsUser attribute was added in 7.0.58

https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57209

Comment: As Links tend to change please provide a quote from the relevant paragraph which are relevant to this question